# Django URL Match Is Not Working

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-1.7

I am having error **Page not found (404)** while accessing following url:

```
http://localhost:8000/blog/blogroll/
```

I am using Python 3.4 & Django 1.7.

Here is my URLS for project:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'weblog.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and this is my url for the app "blog":

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from blog import views

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
       url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
       url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.detail, name='detail'),
       url(r'^blogroll/$', views.blogroll, name='blogroll'),
       #url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name ='results'),
       #url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
       )
```

Besides this the following url is working:

```
http://localhost:8000/blog/
```

I am unable to find out where is the mistake. Please advise.

Thanking you in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `url(r'^blogroll/$', views.blogroll, name='blogroll'),` up one line.

`/blog/anything` is matching your `(?P<slug>...` rule before your `blogroll` rule ever has a chance to match.

You should also end the `slug` regex with `/` outside the capturing group as django tends to like URLs ending with slashes, and your  variable will catch the `/` if using `\S+`